# Raspberry Pi 3 Power supply - chargers for mobile phone

Tags: hardware, power-supply

I ordered new Raspberry Pi 3 for testing Win 10 IoT. Have a question about power supply.

I have two chargers for mobile phone and which one do you recommend to use:

1. Sony Xperia Z2 = 5v 1500mA
2. Galaxy S5 = 5.3v 2000mA

I will use HDMI, keyboard and mouse usb, wifi and GPIO.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I can not answer definitively, not having seen either of the chargers (and i suspect neither have the others who answered). Possibly neither. In the absence of published specifications the only way to know is to test (with a dummy load) and measure the voltage.

The specification for chargers allows up to 1.5A, but the voltage specification is much looser than a USB power specification, and is allowed to drop as low as 3.6v. This is perfectly acceptable for a charger, but not for powering the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you use the Galaxy S5 charger rated at 5.3V 2000mA.  At 2A, this supplies sufficient current for the variety of peripherals you intend to use.

At 5.3V, the output voltage of the charger is higher than the 5V rating of the Pi.  But keep in mind a couple things: The 5V rating of the Pi works fine within +/- 5% range which is 4.75V - 5.25V. And there is a voltage drop that typically occurs within the internal resistance of the charger cable before the current even hits the Pi.  Thoughtfully designed chargers take this into account and put out a little more than 5V to compensate.  So you have a fine charger to use.

Answer (score 1):

One critical input for the RPi-3 to function normal is [power supply](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/raspberry-pi-3-specs-benchmarks/).

I would recommend that you buy a dedicated power supply for your Pi.
Trust me on this one.

To re-iterate, I can only narrate my tale of woes. Official RPi 3 power supply is available online. It's **definitely** worth the money.

Answer (score 0):

The Galaxy S5 Charger gives an optimal amperage for the Raspberry pi, however its voltage is slightly higher than optimal. The RasPi should work with the Xperia Z2, but if the Red light is not steady, that means it has too little power. The S5 charger should be ok, but use it at your own risk...

Answer (score 0):

Either one will work just fine so I would recommend whichever has a longer cable. Per the Raspberry Pi FAQ https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/

Raspberry Pi 3 current capacity 2.5A

Answer (score 0):

The Sony Xperia is on the low side if you'll be using any wireless addons or external HDDs with the RPi 3.

The power output of the S5 charger is in the correct range, but it may have a different problem. Ever since the S4, the Galaxy devices have all come with *Fast Charge* power adapters. I can't say for certainty (outside my scope of experience), but they may do weird and unpredictable things to the RPi.